# How to achieve pull to refresh functionality in android like native facebook android app

Tags: android-listview

I have implemented *pull to refresh* functionality in my application. It refreshes the list if I pull it down.

But my requirement is to show auto refreshing list, as user navigates to that screen every time. Means list will refresh automatically as in native Face-book application.

So please help me by any idea or code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1. You could use a timer and have your app refresh every few minutes.
2. You could implement something much more complicated that uses something like [GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) that would notify the app that there is new data to be refreshed. You would also probably want to only notify the user while they have the app open.